# Jekyll doesn't apply CSS to posts on GitHub Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Yes, I know that this question has already been asked multiple times, and I've applied every solution that I could find, but I still have this issue:

If you visit my Jekyll site ([yasath.github.io](https://yasath.github.io)), the homepage and the tags page in the navbar render the CSS perfectly and look beautiful. However, when I click on a post ([like this one](https://yasath.github.io/2017/09/04/hello-jekyll.html)), the CSS completely fails to render and I end up with an old-looking white background, Times New Roman text page!

My `config.yml` file has the right URLs (as far as I know!), and when I view the source of both pages with Chrome's developer tools, they both import the same CSS file correctly.

Hopefully, someone can give me advice specific to my site! [This is the GitHub repo for the site](https://github.com/yasath/yasath.github.io), and again, here is [the actual site](https://yasath.github.io).

Comment: I had the same issue but fixed it with relative_url:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450554/jekyll-site-works-locally-but-not-on-github-pages/47530487

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links to your stylesheets in your `<head>` section are written as relative links. You have, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/app.min.css">
```

When a URL starts with a directory name like "assets", the browser looks for that directory relative to the URL it's displaying right now. So when you're at `yasath.github.io`, it goes to `yasath.github.io/assets/css/app.min.css`... but when you're at `https://yasath.github.io/2017/09/04/hello-jekyll.html`, it looks for a stylesheet at `https://yasath.github.io/2017/09/04/hello-jekyll.html/assets/css/app.min.css`, which of course doesn't exist.

You want to start your URL with a `/`. That tells the browser to look relative not to the page it's displaying, but to the root of the website. So in your head template use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/app.min.css">
```

...and similarly with all your other stylesheet URLs.

Comment: I am eternally grateful, that works perfectly! I'm quite new to this all :D